# Platform Events and Batch Apex

Tags: platform-event

Firstly,I am not sure if the Raise Paltform event has been released for all or not. Does anyone knows about it?

Another question:-

I wrote a batch class and deliberately generated an exception while updating an Account record.I did not provide an Account Id while updating an Account record...I was hoping it will fire a trigger on the BatchApexErrorEvent and then update the account object with the type of Exception..But  trigger is not getting Fired. Am sure I am missing something here. Please advice.

Simple Batch Apex:-

```
global class AccountBatchApex implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.RaisesPlatformEvents{
  //Database.RaisesPlatformEvents   
    //global integer numberofDirectCustomers = 0;
    
     //integer counter=0;
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        String soqlQuery = 'SELECT Name, AccountNumber, Type From Account limit 10';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(soqlQuery);
    }
     
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Account> scope){
        List<Account>acc12=new list<Account>();
        for (Account acc : scope){
            
            Account a=new account(Name='NYTimes',AccountNumber='1234567890');
            acc12.add(a);
            
            
        }
        Update Acc12;
    }
     
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
         
    }
}
```

Trigger Code which is from the guide.

```
trigger MarkDirtyIfFail on BatchApexErrorEvent (after insert) {
    Set<Id> asyncApexJobIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(BatchApexErrorEvent evt:Trigger.new){
        System.debug('I am in for loop of the Trigger'+evt);
        asyncApexJobIds.add(evt.AsyncApexJobId);
    }
    
    Map<Id,AsyncApexJob> jobs = new Map<Id,AsyncApexJob>(
        [SELECT id, ApexClass.Name FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id IN :asyncApexJobIds]
    );
    
    List<Account> records = new List<Account>();
    for(BatchApexErrorEvent evt:Trigger.new){
        //only handle events for the job(s) we care about
        //
        System.debug('I am in a another for loop of the Trigger'+evt);
        if(jobs.get(evt.AsyncApexJobId).ApexClass.Name == 'AccountBatchApex'){
            for (String item : evt.JobScope.split(',')) {
                System.debug('I am in the third for loop'+item);
                Account a = new Account(
                    Id = (Id)item,
                    ExceptionType__c = evt.ExceptionType,
                    Dirty__c = true
                );
                records.add(a);
            }
        }
    }
    update records;
}
```

Comment: How do you know it's not firing (e.g. maybe it's hitting an error while trying to update the record? Did you check for debug logs?

Comment: I did check debug logs before posting my question and I do not see anything out there.I have debug statements at couple of places in the trigger. I can see execution of batch Apex but nothing related to trigger in debug Log. Just FYI,I am  trying this in dev org..

Comment: Definitely live in all Spring 21 orgs. But in case you make the same mistake I did testing this - make sure you set up the debug for the automated user PE run under - they won't appear under your user debug records

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC...These are the options I have in Debug logs.Debug option:-

1)Automated process
2)Platform integration
3)User
4)Apex class
5)Apex Trigger      ...Which option do u want me to choose?

Comment: Thanks @BritishBoyinDC.I can see debug logs....Thanks a lot once again